TurtleBot3 Navigation Issue with Custom Local Costmap Using Intel RealSense D435i Data (ROS1)
I’m working on navigation with a TurtleBot3 Burger, using a custom local costmap based on data from an Intel RealSense D435i. The RealSense D435i is installed at the front of the TurtleBot. This custom costmap is published to the topic /robot_hld_classifier/map as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid. The navigation stack is built upon the TurtleBot3 Navigation package.
For SLAM mapping and the global costmap, I am using the 360° Laser Distance Sensor (LDS-01) that comes with the TurtleBot3 box set. While most configuration files from the original TurtleBot3 package remain unchanged, I modified the following:

move_base.launch
modified_costmap_common_params_burger.yaml
modified_local_costmap.yaml

Here is my setup:

move_base.launch

<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]" />
  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="/cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false" />

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/modified_costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/modified_local_costmap.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)" />
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)" />
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
</launch>


modified_costmap_common_params_burger.yaml

obstacle_range: 3.0
raytrace_range: 3.5

footprint: [[-0.105, -0.105], [-0.105, 0.105], [0.041, 0.105], [0.041, -0.105]]
#robot_radius: 0.105

inflation_radius: 1.0
cost_scaling_factor: 3.0

map_type: costmap
observation_sources: pointcloud
pointcloud: {sensor_frame: camera_link, data_type: OccupancyGrid, topic: /robot_hld_classifier/map, marking: true, clearing: true}


modified_local_costmap.yaml

local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true

  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.02

  plugins:
    - {name: terrain_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

terrain_layer:
  map_topic: "/robot_hld_classifier/map"
  subscribe_to_updates: true

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 1
  cost_scaling_factor: 3

The Issue
Using the default configuration (which relies only on the LDS-01 for both local and global costmaps), the robot performs well and avoids dynamic obstacles (like people walking in the environment) [Fig. 2]. However, when I switch to my custom local costmap (using data from the RealSense D435i), the robot cannot avoid dynamic obstacles—it does not react to them at all [Fig. 3].

Fig. 1 Navigation using TurtleBot3 in an environment without dynamic obstacles

Fig. 2 Navigation using TurtleBot3 with the default configuration in an environment with dynamic obstacles

Fig. 3 Navigation using TurtleBot3 with a custom local costmap based on Intel RealSense D435i data in an environment with dynamic obstacles
What I Have Tried

Checked that the RealSense D435i data is being correctly processed by my pipeline.
Verified that the /robot_hld_classifier/map topic publishes valid nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid data.
Confirmed that the local and global costmaps are being correctly loaded from the launch files.

What could be causing the TurtleBot3 to fail in avoiding dynamic obstacles with my custom costmap? Could it be related to the costmap plugins, update frequency, or the way I configured the terrain layer with the custom topic? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.
